# Materialize and Bootstrap input fields cache last state and do not respect my chosen state

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, materialize

Take a look at the documentation here:

https://materializecss.com/checkboxes.html

If you check the top checkbox and then reload the page - the top checkbox is still checked and not reset. If you look at the source, the checkbox has no "checked" on it.

How do I get materialize checkboxes to work as I expect? This is a big nuisance for me since a checkbox can appear as checked but not be posted when the form is submitted. Is it my browser? Is it Materialize? Is there a solution?

It works correctly if I press hard refresh - ctrl+f5, but not when I press ctrl+r or refresh button in the browser. The issue is the same with Bootstrap. Normal checkboxes work just as I expect them to.

[image: Proof]

Answer (score 0):

I made some more research into this and found a solution that fixed it for me:

**autocomplete="off"** on the input fields.

There seem to be other solutions as well by disabling caching by using "Cache-Control: no-store" header serverside or in meta tag - but this did not work with me so I assume this is an obsolete solution for this kind of issue from a time where browsers respected headers for how to cache html content.

The default is a good thing if it is a form for user input, but I needed it not to be this way because I build an administrative insert/update system and need to have the system to correctly show what is stored rather than reflect and remember what was last clicked.